# Excel VBA autofiltering separate sections

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a large excel file with multiple separate regions and it looks like it isn't possible to add filtering to separate rows and columns not next to each other so I'm trying to use VBA to make the filter icon show in specific places.

```vb
Sub Filtering ()
Worksheets("sheet5").Range("BB22:BU55,AD55:AZ264,E55:AB264"). _
AutoFilter
End Sub
```

When I use this code it only applies filters to one range.

Comment: One worksheet can only contain 1 filter, the moment you add filter on another range, the previous filter will be gone, please try it without VBA you will notice it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have many filters on the sheet, you can previously convert ranges to ListObjects ('smart' tables) and then operate with filters. Note that filtering a table will affect other tables in the same rows :

```
Option Explicit

Sub Filtering()
    Dim rng As Range, area As Range
    
    With Worksheets("sheet5")
        Set rng = .Range("BB22:BU55,AD55:AZ264,E55:AB264")
        For Each area In rng.Areas
            .ListObjects.Add Source:=area
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This worked well, but I found that it also worked without VBA by converting the individual sections to tables.